# count occurrences of given value across multiple ranges

Tags: excel, excel-formula, count, countif

**WORKAROUND**: turns out, `COUNTIF` ignores text cells, so I can just use a single range and ensure all comments are stored as text. However, if someone could answer this for cases where the comments might be numbers, I would be very appreciative.

---

In Excel: I would like to get a count of how many cells contain a given value, which (I assume) should be very simple using `COUNTIF` or `COUNTIFS` functions. However, my issue is that I would like to count across multiple non-continuous ranges (i.e. multiple non-adjacent columns in the same row) such that I get a count of all X-valued cells in that row.

The data I'm working with is set up with some columns being used for "score" and some for "comments", and I need to count the number of, say, scores of 1 in the row:

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | **score1** | **comment1** | **score2** | **comment2** | **extraneousCol** | **score3** | **comment3** | **count1** |
| **2** | 1 | Lorem | 2 | Ipsum | irrelevant | 1 | Dolor | `2` |
| **3** | 2 | Sit | 2 | Amet | impertinent | 0 | Consectetur | `0` |
| **4** | 1 | Adipiscing | 0 | Elit | inapplicable | 2 | Praesent | `1` |

The final column is what I would *like* the formula to output, i.e. outputting a count of how many cells have value `1` in the respective row. As you can see, there are also columns that break up the regularity of the `score`/`comment` pattern. These make it harder to automatically select ranges, as I can't simply select every 2nd cell.

Here's what I've tried:

- `=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(INDIRECT({"A2","C2","F2"}),"=1"))` uses `INDIRECT` to work around the one-range requirement of `COUNTIF`, and `SUMPRODUCT` to output a single value, but it's a pain to enter the cell locations with quotes in `INDIRECT({...})`
- `=COUNTIFS(A2,"=1",C2,"=1",F2,"=1")` works but is also a pain to input all the criteria

Maybe my problem is one of selecting multiple ranges, and not of counting across ranges? Let me know if I should move this question.

Edit: `COUNTIF` will ignore text cells, so **in this case**, I'm good to use a single range (i.e. the row) and single criterion, i.e. `=COUNTIF(A2:G2,"=1")`.

Comment: Why is row 3's count 0? Also, since the rest of the columns are text, `countif` will ignore them so you can just do range on entire row. Edit: `countif(a2:g2,2)` should work. Edit2: oh, you are counting 1 not 2? If so, `countif(a2:g2,1)`.

Comment: @findwindow oh lol, thanks for the edit! Also, I didn't realize `COUNTIF` would ignore text! Thanks

I'll just make sure those comment fields don't have a random lone number anywhere that will interfere (format all comments as text should do it?)

I'll edit the post to include the fix :)

Comment: Comments with numbers in the field will still count as text. I think.

Comment: Sorry, I meant a cell in one of the comment cols containing a lone number for whatever reason. Text that includes a number should still be text. @findwindow

Comment: `=COUNTIF(A2:G2,"=1")` this should give you desired result. Do you need still help?

Comment: @Harun24hr yes, this is exactly what I determined would work in my case. It's in the edit at the bottom of the question. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make sure it counts correctly even if the comment would be `1` you could avoid COUNTIF and use SUMPRODUCT solely by creating an array of TRUE's in the header starting with the text `score` and multiply that array with TRUE's in the current row with value 1:

`=SUMPRODUCT((LEFT($A$1:$G$1,5)="score")*(A2:G2=1))`

Comment: this is perfect! I didn't know Excel could do arrays like this, thanks for the tip!

Comment: Because of the multiplier `*` in between the arrays the TRUE's and FALSE's are translated to 1's and 0's. If you'd want that in a single array you'd have to wrap it in `N()` or `--()`. For example `=SUMPRODUCT(--(A2:G2=1))`. `*` between  boolean arrays can be read as `AND`, `+` as `OR`, `/` can be used to create intentional error values to filter them out: (f.e. `1/()`) it can be used in combination with AGGREGATE for instance.